# Why does this iOS app take very long time to pop up string to UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift

I created a UILabel in storyboard in order to show the response from the server. However, it takes **very long time** to show the string from the server. It did work, just take almost 1 minute.

I use `print` to check if there is any delay in the server, but the application will print the response in debug area immediately once opening the application. I guess it should be app's problem.

I check the code and looks fine, works well. Only has delay issue. Can anyone have any idea? (This is a tvOS app using Swift 3.0 BTW)

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDataDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var RandomString: UILabel!

    let UUIDValue = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString

    func sendRequest(url: String, parameters: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void) -> URLSessionTask {
        let parameterString = parameters
        let requestURL = URL(string:"\(url)\(parameterString)")!

        print("requestURL = \(requestURL)")

        var request = URLRequest(url: requestURL)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: completionHandler)
        task.resume()

        return task
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.sendRequest(url: "http://www.google.com/api", parameters: UUIDValue, completionHandler:{data, response, error in

            print (self.UUIDValue)

            guard error == nil && data != nil else {
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

            print("responseString = \(responseString)")

            //If app receives "true" response from server, go to Home screen.
            if responseString == "true" {
                let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tab") as UIViewController

                self.present(viewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
            //If app receives "false" response from server, display the response from server.
            else {
                self.RandomString.text = responseString as String?
            }
        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you setting the label's text? Make sure you're doing so on the main thread.

Comment: I just paste the complete code to this thread, just realized it was incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting the label's text inside of the server call, which is not guaranteed to be on the main thread. All UI updates need to happen on the main thread. Try this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.RandomString.text = responseString as String?
}
```